# Ruby on Rails 4 Routing/Views/Path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 questions:

I have a controller called homepage. I have a view called samplegraph in my homepage's view directory. I want to get the routing working correctly such that **www.homepage.com/samplegraph takes me to the samplegraph page.**

As far as I can tell, the route for it in routes.rb should be something like this:

```
GET 'homepage/samplegraph' => 'homepage#showgraph1'
```

If I'm understanding rails routing correctly, this statement routes GET requests to homepage/samplegraph to the homepage controller's showgraph1 action. At this point I'm not particularly sure what the showgraph1 action should be in order to render the view page(samplegraph). At the moment the action is simply empty. I don't really know what to put here.

**Second question:**

Also, while I was researching rails routing, I was looking into resource based routing. For my purposes, I don't need most of the stuff generated by that. One thing I am interested in is that invoking resource based routing automatically generates Paths for you via helpers(I think?).

How would I generate a Path for my route, such that I'd be able to use a link_to method to link various parts of the application together? Any help/comments would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you want to get 'samplegraph' page rendered by hitting 'www.homepage.com/samplegraph', you will need to update your route.

Replace

```
get 'homepage/samplegraph' => 'homepage#showgraph1'
```

with

```
get '/samplegraph' => 'homepage#showgraph1'
```

Now in `showgraph1` action of your `homepage` controller, you will need to render `samplegraph` view page at last line of the action.

```
render 'samplegraph'
```

As of you **second question**, just hit `rake routes` on your terminal from your app directory. It will show all routes with helpers which you can use with `link_to`. You will need to append `_path` to those routes while using with `link_to`

Comment: Great! As you are new to SO, I would like to suggest you that being a good learner and contributor, you should accept the answer which solves your problem

Comment: Is there a way to mark multiple answers as having helped? Mandeep's answer helped me out with the helpers/Path question.

Comment: Sorry.. that's not possible :( You can't accept multiple answers but you can vote for many...

Answer (score 0):

Like `@RAJ` said first of all you need to change your route to

```
get '/samplegraph' => 'homepage#showgraph1'
```

`At this point I'm not particularly sure what the showgraph1 action should be in order to render the view page(samplegraph)`

***Rails doesn't care if your action is empty or not, it'll still render your actions view even if it's empty.*** Since your action is named showgraph1 so it'll make rails look for showgraph1.html.erb with path views/homepage/showgraph1.html.erb

To change this behavior you need to use `render 'samplegraph'` in your action

`One thing I am interested in is that invoking resource based routing automatically generates Paths for you via helpers(I think?)`

*Rails generate path and url helpers for each route and it doesn't depend on how your routes are defined but **you can customize your helper methods by specifying [`as:`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-as-in-nested-resources) option***

```
get 'homepage/samplegraph' => 'homepage#showgraph1', as: 'showgraph'
```

This will make your helper methods [**showgraph_path and showgraph_url**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers)

Comment: Ok, so my action wasn't rendering the first time because my action name and view name didn't correspond.

Comment: @user3731368 that's because by default rails look for a view with same name as your actions. You need to mention it in your action by using render

Comment: Also, so if I wanted to use link_to in order to create a link between my pages, would it be this? <%= link_to 'Link Title', showgraph_path %>

Comment: @user3731368 yeah showgraph_path will give your path helper. You can see all the helper methods by running rake routes in terminal